# Rust Error "Address family not supported by protocol family"

Tags: postgresql, rust

I'm trying to connect to a postgres database using Rust. And I get an error:

> Error: Error { kind: Connect, cause: Some(Os { code: 47, kind:
> Uncategorized, message: "Address family not supported by protocol
> family" }) }

I tried using IP and domain address. I can't connect to either the local or remote server :(
Can the operating system or hardware affect this? I am using a mac with m1 processor

```
#Cargo.toml
[dependencies]
postgres = "0.19"

#main.rs
use postgres::{Client, NoTls, Error};
fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let conn_string = "host=host user=user password=pass dbname=dbname";
    let mut client = Client::connect(conn_string, NoTls)?;
    let rows = client.query("SELECT * FROM table", &[])?;
    for row in rows {
        let id: i32 = row.get("id");
        println!("id: {}", id);
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question [Address family not supported by protocol family](/q/4356646/2189130)?